# How Can I create a function with recursion to create a tree through a dictionary?

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I have to create this tree:

```
               _____________music_____________            
              |                               |            
    _________rock_________           ________jazz_______   
   |          |           |         |          |        |  
origines   rock&roll   hard rock   origines  ragtime   swing
                                    |                      
                                   1900
                                    |
                                  origines
```

I've created the class to iterate the tree and I only need the function to create the tree. But I can't understand how a dictionary could be rewritten as a tree through a recursive function.

Comment: Can you show some of the code you have already written?

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can be used to represent a tree by nesting. An example:

```
tree = {
    'rock': {
         'origines': {},
         'rock&roll': {},
         'hard rock': {},
    },
    'jazz': {
        'origines': {
             '1900': {
                 ...
             },
        },
    },
}
```